# Use Keyboard shortcuts while computer Locked

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a monitor & keyboard (MX Keys) connected to 2x PC's - and the monitor input buttons are hard to reach.

I have bash scripts to change monitor inputs using ddccontrol, and a keyboard shortcut on F1 and F2 to switch inputs (they call the bash scripts).  This is running on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

When on my work windows laptop - my ubuntu is locked (5min time out).  I can not use the shortcuts.

Can i make the keyboard shortcuts run even when locked?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Locked" by definition means: block access. To make your shortcuts run, unlock the machine or keep it unlocked.

An alternative approach may involve setting up an ssh connection. You could then execute the script through SSH from the windows machine so it switches the keyboard. Still, you will need to unlock starting to work on the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: I have commands to run from windows, except my wife doesn't use that machine, and sometimes it sits asleep already - same issue.

Comment: Increase time before automatic lock, lock manually when you leave the workplace.